# Apache domain routes set up

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Im not sure the right way to ask this question that is probably why I cant find a solution. I have a minecraft server set up called multicraft. To access this website i go to my ip\multicraft. I want this to be access from just the ip instead. What do I google to find out how to do this or just how do I do it?